# Alolan Legendaries in the Blessed and the Dammed

Tags: content-identification, pokemon-tabletop-united

I suspect that the supplement "The Blessed and the Damned" came out before the Alolan dex was added. However, now that we -do- have stats for these Legendary Pokémon such as the Tapu's, Solgaleo and Lunala, is there someplace where I can find information regarding them in the same strain as what the aforementioned supplement adds for earlier Legendaries?

Comment: Concerned that this is a recommendation question, but it's basically equivalent to a content identification question.

Comment: "Content identification" sounds accurate, yes. Are those not allowed?

Comment: totally allowed. Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I could find no such *official* document

In fact, the only official news I could find on [the official site](https://pokemontabletop.com/) related to *The Blessed and the Damned* was [this blog post](https://pokemontabletop.com/a-fresh-start-and-ptu-1-05-news/) from November 2019 which merely states that it will be getting a visual re-design that I do not believe it has received yet.

There *are*, on the official [tapatalk/forum](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/pokemon_tabletop/pokemon-tabletop-united-f13/), pinned messages include [an official full Gen 7 Pokédex](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/pokemon_tabletop/gen-7-pokedex-t5995.html) and [an official full Gen 8 Pokédex](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/pokemon_tabletop/gen-8-pokedex-t7257.html). Both of these were posted by the user DataNinja.

She has actually made [quite a lot of homebrew](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/pokemon_tabletop/dataninja-s-homebrew-compilation-t7194.html) including [a revamp to *The Blessed and the Damned*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cN-SRG0GIzRyVbJwkdfeplVQH-hVf9Kk/view) that adds in legendaries such as the Tapus and Zacian and Zamazenta as well as balancing the Gifts and Auras of the original. She is *now* one of the Developers for PTU but she was not a Dev when she made this homebrew. As such, it is not an official release, but it is almost certainly the closest thing you'll find (at the time of writing).